# How to merge two branches (my local with a remote branch)

Tags: git, shell

I created the branch **testDB** and I want to pull from the **databasecheck**, which a colleague's branch, into the former.

I know that I have first to fetch and then to merge but I do not know how to do it exactly.

So, given the names of the branches that I have to merge can someone show me exactly how to do it ?

Comment: Read the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to learn the basics.

Comment: @poke I used these commands : `git fetch origin databasecheck` and after that `git merge origin/testDB` but the shell prints _merge: origin/testDB - not something we can merge_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is `git pull origin databasecheck` while you have your branch checked out. This will fetch from the `origin` and then merge the `origin/databasecheck` into your local `testDB` branch

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to the branch you want to merge into (testDB in this case) then run the command
`git merge databasecheck`

This would merge databasecheck into testDB.